# React-Native async Array.map = undefined is not an Object

Tags: javascript, react-native, async-await

I try to create my first hybrid App with ReactNative. I have an issue with my Array.map…

```
class HomeScreen extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    captured: false,
    wished: false,
    exchanged: false,
    data: {}
  };

  async getPokemonFromApiAsync() {
    try {
      this.setState({isLoading: true});
      let response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=0&offset=20');
return this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: await response.json()
       });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
  }

  (...)    

  componentWillMount() {
      this.getPokemonFromApiAsync()
  }

  (...)

  result = (result = this.state.data.results) => {
      console.log('test', this.state.data);
      return (
         <View>

             (...)

             result.map( (item, index) => {

             (...)

             }
         </View>
      )
  } 
}
```

I don't understand, why my function getPokemonFromApiAsync is empty. iOS Simulator returns a TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.map')

And when adding a constructor like:

```
constructor(props) {
   super(props)
   this.getPokemonFromApiAsync = This.getPokemonFromApiAsync.bind(this)
}
```

I have an many errors in console:

Warning: Can't call %s on a component that is not yet mounted. This is a no-op, but it might indicate a bug in your application. Instead, assign to `this.state` directly or define a `state = {};` class property with the desired state in the %s component., setState, HomeScreen

For me, it's normal…

What is a good lifecycle for an asynchronous Http request?

Comment: Drop **await** in the state and you will be good.

Comment: Thank you. But i have same error.

console.log('test', this.state.data) return Object {}.

My problem comes the datas is retrieve but not retrieve in state.

Comment: Well, you are missing configuration object in your fetch statement. make sure you provide those. I suspect your fetch is failing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error is caused by how you have set up your initial `data` in state.

You have set it up as:

```
state = {
  isLoading: false,
  captured: false,
  wished: false,
  exchanged: false,
  data: {} // <- here you define it as an object, with no parameters
};
```

You should be setting it as an object with a results parameter`. So your initial state should look like

```
state = {
  isLoading: false,
  captured: false,
  wished: false,
  exchanged: false,
  data: { results: [] } // <- here you should define the results inside the object
};
```

The reason you are getting the error:

```
TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.map')
```

Is because on the initial render, before your fetch response has come back, it is trying to `map` over `this.state.data.results` which doesn't exist. You need to make sure that there is an initial value for `results` in the state.

That should stop the initial error, however you will have to make sure that what you are saving into state for `data` is also an array, otherwise you will continue to get the same error.

---

`componentWillMount` has been deprecated and you should be using `componentDidMount`.

Also as you are calling an async function inside you `componentWillMount` you should refactor it in the following way:

```
async componentDidMount() {
  await this.getPokemonFromApiAsync()
}
```

So that the mounting doesn't occur until the fetch request has been completed.

---

I would also refactor your `getPokemonFromApiAsync` so that you get the `response.json()` before trying to set it into state. You also don't need the return statement as `this.setState` doesn't return anything.

```
async getPokemonFromApiAsync() {
  try {
    this.setState({isLoading: true});
    let response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=0&offset=20');
    let data = await response.json(); // get the data 
    this.setState({
      isLoading: false,
      data: data // now set it to state
    });
  } catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

---

#### Snack:

Here is a very simple snack showing the code working https://snack.expo.io/@andypandy/pokemon-fetch

Code for snack:

```
export default class App extends React.Component {

  state = {
    isLoading: false,
    captured: false,
    wished: false,
    exchanged: false,
    data: { results: [] } // <- here you should define the results inside the object
  };

  getPokemonFromApiAsync = async () => {
    try {
      this.setState({ isLoading: true });
      let response = await fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=0&offset=20');
      let data = await response.json(); // get the data
      this.setState({
        isLoading: false,
        data: data // now set it to state
      });
    } catch (error) {
      console.error(error);
    }
  }

  async componentDidMount () {
    await this.getPokemonFromApiAsync();
  }

  render () {
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
        {this.state.data.results.map(item => <Text>{item.name}</Text>)}
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello visitor of future, for more informations: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/network#using-fetch

Answer (score 1):

Best way using axios library github [link](https://github.com/axios/axios)

```
npm install axios
```

Finally, weekly downloads are more than 4,000,000+ Github Starts 50,000+

Answer (score 0):

A better way is to implement your state values when your promise is resolved using "then".

```js
let response = fetch('https://pokeapi.co/api/v2/pokemon/?limit=0&offset=20')
  .then((response) => {
     this.setState({
       isLoading: false,
       data: response.json()
     });
  });
```

Maybe you can process your data (`result.map`) in the Promise callback and directly insert the result in your component.

And by the way, XHR calls are generally processed in the `componentDidMount` method.

Answer (score 0):

The reason you are getting the error `TypeError: Undefined is not an object (evaluating 'result.map')` is that you are getting the `result` from `this.state.data.results`, but because data is async, at the first time it renders, data is `{}` (because you set it in the state), so `data.result` is `undefined` and you can't use `.map()` in a undefined.

To solve this, you can check if `data.result` is not undefined, before render it.

```
  return (
     <View>

         (...)

         result && result.map( (item, index) => {

         (...)

         }
     </View>
  )
```